# AWS - How to make my resources visible to the entire organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS account, the account was added to an organization via the invite feature. The root account of the organizations is unable to see my resources(lambda functions,database,etc)

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65665594/14843902) 
existing thead.